# use Array.indexOf for relatively big arrays

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to achieve `indexOf` functionality, to find out if a string is on an array, for very big arrays relatively fast? When my array grows beyond 40,000 values, my app freezes for a few seconds.

Consider the following code:

```
var arr = [];

function makeWord()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    return text;
}
function populateArr(){
  for (var i=0;i<40000;i++){
    arr[i] = makeWord();
  }
  console.log("finished populateArr");
}
function checkAgainst(){
  for (var i=0;i<40000;i++){
    var wordToSearch = makeWord();
    if (isFound(wordToSearch)){
      console.log("found "+wordToSearch);
    }
  }
  console.log("finished checkAgainst");
}

function isFound(wordToSearch){
  //return $.inArray(wordToSearch,arr) > -1;
  return arr.indexOf(wordToSearch) > -1;
}

populateArr();
checkAgainst();
```

[**FIDDLE here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9LSYE/)

In this code I'm populating an array `arr` with 40k random strings. Than, in `checkAgainst` I'm creating 40,000 other random strings, and than each one is checked if it is found on `arr`. This makes chrome freeze for about 2 seconds. Opening the profiler on Chrome DevTools, I see that `isFound` is obviously expensive in terms of CPU. even if I lower the for loop iterations number to just 4000 in `checkAgainst` , it still freezes for about a second or so.

In reality, I have a chrome extension and an array of keywords that grows to about 10k strings. Than, I have to use `Array.indexOf` to see if chucks of 200 other keywords are in that array. This makes my page freeze every once in a while, and from this example I suspect this is the cause. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using keys in an object instead:

```
var arr = {};

function makeWord() // unchanged
function populateArr(){
  for (var i=0;i<40000;i++){
    arr[makeWord()] = true;
  }
  console.log("finished populateArr");
}
function checkAgainst() // unchanged

function isFound(wordToSearch){
  return arr[wordToSearch];
}

populateArr();
checkAgainst();
```

If you then need the array of words, you can use `Object.keys(arr)`

Alternatively, combine the two: have an array *and* an object. Use the object to look up if a word is in the array, or the array to get the words themselves. This would be a classic compromise, trading memory usage for time.